# Installing Varnish as per the Varnish Book?

Tags: varnish

I have a vanilla Debian DigitalOcean machine and I'm trying to follow the 'developer' course in the Varnish Book. I've got to [the first exercise, Installation](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/Getting_started.html#exercise-installation).

I've installed Apache and got it running on port 8080 (if I go to http://my.ip.xxx.xxx:8080 I see the Apache2 Debian default page. I've also installed Varnish, so steps 1-3 are fine.

Now I'm trying to follow steps 4 and 5. I've edited `/etc/default/varnish` as follows:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:1234 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

And I've edited `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` as follows:

```
backend default {
   .host = "localhost";
   .port = "8080";
}
```

Then I've run `service varnish start`, which produces no errors.

But if I go to `http://my.ip.xxx.xxx` (i.e. with no port number) I just see nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

If I run `netstat -ntlp` as suggested in the book, I see Varnish on ports 6081 and 6082, and Apache on port 8080, but nothing on port 80.

Comment: If I run `varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:1234 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m -d` at the command line, and type `start`, then everything works OK. So perhaps it's something to do with `/etc/default/varnish` and `/etc/init.d/varnish` not playing nicely?

Comment: You have to restart varnish after making changes to /etc/default/varnish to have it listen on port 80 instead of port 6081. Try running "sudo service varnish restart".

Comment: What Debian version are you running on? Could be a sysv vs systemd issue.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but had this problem myself. In my case I had to edit `/lib/systemd/system/varnishncsa.service` as SystemD was taking over the legacy InitD.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :80 -T localhost:1234 -f /etc/varnish/abadcer.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Then you commit the changes and restart Varnish

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service varnish restart
```